# How to resume interrupted download of specific part of file automatically in curl?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, resume-download

I'm working with curl in Linux. I'm downloading a part of a file from Media-fire using bad internet connection , the download always stops after few minutes and when i use the parameter `-C -`  instead of continue downloading only the part of a file i mentioned from where the download stopped , it starts downloading the hole file .

This is command i have used :

```
curl -v -o file.part8 -r3000000001-3200000000 --retry 999 --retry-max-time 0 -C - http://download2331.mediafire.com/58gp2u3yjuzg/6upaohqwd8kdi9n/Olarila+High+Sierra+2020.raw.bz2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that server doesn't support byte ranges

Answer (score 1):

i tried with :

```
curl -L -k -C - -O    --header "Range: bytes=0-1000000" https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/20.10/release/kubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

and i get :

```
curl: (33) HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.
```

it seems that the problem is in the server.